# Why according to distribution graph it's normally distributed, but Jarque-Bera test shows non-normally distributed?

Tags: statistical-significance, data-visualization, normality-assumption

I am working on Kaggle's house pricing exercise and I cannot understand something. I watch and read articles on normality tests, and more specifically JB test, but I cannot understand why according to my understanding of that test I need to reject the null hypothesis (which is the normal distribution) and conclude it is a non-normal distribution when the distribution graph shows a very close result to a normal distribution?

```
Jarque-Bera test = 171.236, with p-value 6.55459e-038
```

So from that result, if I am correct, I reject null and conclude the data are not normally distributed. But then this is the distribution graph (n=1460):

[image]

PS. The Y var is log of price and the x is year. Could the problem be that year is not a continuous variable?

Comment: Could you explain in what sense you believe this histogram is "close" to a Normal distribution?  In effect, you are confronting a formal test with an unexplained intuition; by default, you should believe the test and use its results to modify your intuition.

Comment: I was just confused that according to the graph, it seems the data is normally distributed becasue it follows the Bell curve shape, so I became unsure whther I understand the test meaning correctly. However, reading your answer, can I conclude that the test will win over the graph and this is because the graph actually is not perfect Bell shape..?

Comment: That's right.  Unfortunately, the Jarque-Bera test is difficult to visualize with a histogram (because it is based on higher moments of the distribution, which no histogram explicitly shows).  You *can* evaluate normality by comparing the bar *areas* to the *areas* predicted by the fitted Normal curve, using the principles of a Chi-squared test of goodness of fit.  By looking closely, I see that the bar for the interval [-0.1,0.1] is too high while the one for [0.3,0.5] is too low. Given there are 1460 data points, you can estimate that these show significant deviations from normality.